# How to properly encode terms in a Solr facet search

Tags: solr, filter, space, facet

When I perform a search with the following Solr query I get what I want: "courses" that have been tagged with the terms 'PHP' or 'Programming'.

```
q=[* TO *]&facet=on&facet.field=facet_contenttype&fq=facet_contenttype:mediaitems_course&facet.field=facet_wmterm&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming)
```

Now, I want to also include courses that have been tagged with 'C# .NET'. The entire string 'C# .NET' is one tag in the CMS I am using. I have tried the following possibilities for the facet_wmterm filter query.

```
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR C# .NET) // no quotes
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR 'C# .NET') // quotes
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR 'C#+.NET') // quotes and replaced space for + sign
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR C#%2b.NET) // no quotes, encoded + sign
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR 'C#%2b.NET') // quotes, encoded + sign
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR 'C%23+.NET') // quotes, encoded # sign
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR C%23+.NET) // no quotes, encoded # sign
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR 'C%23%2B.NET') // quotes, encoded # and + signs
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR Programming OR C%23%2B.NET) // no quotes, encoded # and + signs
and a lot more options....
```

Strangely, all the above options return ALL courses, no matter what they are tagged with and I am pretty sure I am not looking at caching, because removing the 'C# .NET' bit gives me the initial, correct 'PHP or Programming' results.

I'd LOVE to learn how to include 'C# .NET' in my facet query, because I am about to go slightly mad :) Thanks!

Comment: What does the datatype look like in schema.xml.  The answer will vary depending on whether or not you use StandardTokenizerFactory, LowerCaseFilterFactory, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating the field name does have an effect.

```
&fq=facet_wmterm:Test1 OR PHP
```

..is giving me ALL results (= wrong) and repeating the field name like this

```
&fq=facet_wmterm:Test1 OR facet_wmterm:PHP
```

..is giving me courses with Test1 or PHP only (= correct!). Thanks for that Ansari.

This still didn't help me to properly query for .NET C# courses though, because I was also incorrectly escaping special characters. In Solr you can use quotes to search literally for what is between the quotes, but you have to use **double quotes** instead of the single quotes I was using. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

This worked for me:

```
&fq=(facet_wmterm:Test1 OR "C# .NET")
```

Comment: Yes I was only pointing out one issue - I left the escaping issue for you to figure out. That was just an example rule. In general, double quotes to search literally and URL-encode special characters. You can use the admin section to figure out exactly what needs to be encoded how.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out which escaping scheme works best, try to prefix each term with the field name. So for example, taking your third line, try this:

```
&fq=(facet_wmterm:PHP OR facet_wmterm:Programming OR facet_wmterm:'C#+.NET') // quotes and replaced space for + sign
```

The reason is that each term must be specified with which field it needs to be in, otherwise it's searched for in the default field (`text`). For escaping issues, literals must be encoded in double quotes, and other special symbols that need to appear literally must be URL-encoded.